# How To change a part of src attribute unknown

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, src

I'm using a javascript code that find an img element and preview it after replacing a part of its `src` attribute.

This part is created by user and i can't determine it.

Here is the code:

```
<img src="' + i[0].src.replace("/s**/", "/s726/") + '" />
```

`**` represents the unknown numbers ranged from 0 to 1600.
I'm looking for a regex or another way that dynamically gets this value and changes it to `726`

Thank you

**#Update Solution:**

```
<img src="' + i[0].src.replace(/\/s[0-9]+(-*c*)\//, "/s726/") + '" />
```

Comment: Try to make your question more clear. What is the code you have posted? Is it yours? Why there are unquoted parts? When you post excerpt of code, try to make it understandable (as it, we don't know if it is javascript code, html code, a string or whatever you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
i[0].src.replace(/s([01]?[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]|1600)[^0-9]/, "s726")
```